# client.GetChannel(%channelID%) return null

Tags: c#, .net, null, discord, discord.net

> Im creting discord bot via discord.Net v 1.0.2

And  I want to get specific channel from my server Im trying to get that channel via **`Client.GetChannel(%channelID%)`** (Client is property of type DiscordSocketClient in my bot class) but that method return me only null and I just cant figure out why. I searched on lots of similiar post on internet but nothing work. There is start method of my bot and method where Im trying to get channel:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await Client.StartAsync();
    Client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;
    Client.Connected += Client_Connected;
    Logger.WriteLog("Bot started");
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task Client_Connected()
{
    var channel = Client.GetChannel(414543303187496962);
}
```

Comment: How is it returning null? What are you doing to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Client.Ready` event Handler instead, and make sure that the bot is indeed in that specific channel, and it should work this time.

So it would look like this:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await Client.StartAsync();
    Client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;
    Client.Ready += Client_Ready;
    Logger.WriteLog("Bot started");
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task Client_Ready()
{
    var channel = Client.GetChannel(414543303187496962);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot its works for me :D. But I dont understand what is the diference between the client.Ready and client.Connected :/

Comment: @PetrKotáb I am not really clear myself, so someone can correct me if I am wrong. Basically the client a `Connected`, `LoggedIn` and `Ready` eventhandler state for us to use. And whenever you run the client, it goes from `Connected`, to `LoggedIn`, finally with `Ready` state. I am guessing that `Connected` state refers to when the client manages to establish a connection to Discord, but have not logged in yet. And the `ready` state refers to the client having successfully loaded all it's own client-user contents after logged in.